# Can't get openpyxl data validation to work

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to enable data validation on a group of cells, as per the openpyxl [documentaion](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html), but when I open the file nothing has changed.
I was already successful with locking/unlocking cells in this workbook in another part of my program.

```
import openpyxl

file_path = 'file.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file_path, read_only=False)
ws = workbook[sheet_name]
cells = [ws.cell(1,1), ws.cell(1,2), ws.cell(1,3)]

validator_type = 'whole'
validator = openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation(type=validator_type)
ws.add_data_validation(validator)

for cell in cells:
    validator.add(cell)

workbook.save(file_path)
```

While trying to solve this, I have:

- Read the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html)
- Simplified the function to the snippet above.
- Googled it for a few hours, including here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but this is an example from the documentation:
'
Any whole number:
dv = DataValidation(type="whole")
'

Comment: 1. Your comments are extremely unhelpful
2. This is a complete example. Further down in the docs there are other, different, complete examples

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the docs example you refer to is invalid. I tested it myself and it won't work – at least in Excel 365.

The reason is that the `whole` validation **requires** an operator and (a) limiting value(s). Take a look at the source code [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/worksheet/datavalidation.py?ref_type=heads#L102).